# iframe element returns undefined after onload event?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

EDIT: Is there no one who can shed some light on this issue? Anything would be appreciated. :)

I have a script that is supposed to check to see if an elements html contains a given string..

When these elements do exist, my code throws this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'outerHTML' of null`

This is the line: `let check = document.querySelector("#iframe_${globalI}").contentWindow.document.querySelector(".Row"+inc).outerHTML`

I then check to see if the string includes a check string.. IE: `check.includes("Pre Trip")`

If I run this line directly in the console it works and returns true... So what is going on here..?? How can I get this check to pass..?

I have this check executing after a setTimeout of 20 seconds, then wrapped again in another setTimeout for 500ms as I was trying to figure this out..

Also, I need to note that there are no XSS / CORS issues.

Here is my code..

````js
        function checkRowCount(x){
      console.log("Row count called on "+x);
      let rowCount = 0;
      for(let i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        if(typeof(document.querySelector(`#iframe_${x}`).contentWindow.document.querySelector('.Row'+i)) != 'undefined' && document.querySelector(`#iframe_${x}`).contentWindow.document.querySelector('.Row'+i) != null){
          rowCount++;
        }
      }
      console.log(rowCount);
      return rowCount;
    }

    let globalCompiler = []; //globalCompiler[globalI] = {unit: unitNumber[globalI], data: ["X", " ", "NO POST TRIP]}

    let unitNumber = [1031,1743,1744,1986,3239,3256,3257,4024,4062,4063,4064,4065,4247,4309,4315,4326,4327,4334,4335,4337,4350,4382,4385,7166,7380,7381,8765,8823,8945,8950,8988,10720,17045,17163,40014,40069,40122,40380,80129,80188,80700,80701,80702,80728,80831,80852,80875,"80876","81027","81038","401288","401306","402409","60099T","CH889","CH890","SR31077","T19","U5509","U6660","U6667","U6675","U8854","US1025T"];
    let url = "http://winweb.cleanharbors.com/Vehicle/VehicleTDSearch.aspx?SearchType=DVIR";

    function iframeLoaded(selector, unit, setDate, callback){
      document.querySelector(`#iframe_${selector}`).contentWindow.document.querySelector("#txtStartDate").value = setDate;
      document.querySelector(`#iframe_${selector}`).contentWindow.document.querySelector("#txtEndDate").value = setDate;
      document.querySelector(`#iframe_${selector}`).contentWindow.document.querySelector("#txtVhcleNo").value = unit;
      document.querySelector(`#iframe_${selector}`).contentWindow.document.querySelector("#btnRetrieve").click();
    }

    let loadFinished = {};

    for(let dec = 0; dec < unitNumber.length; dec++){
      loadFinished[unitNumber[dec]] = false;
    }
    console.log(loadFinished);

    for(let globalI = 0; globalI < 3; globalI++){

      globalCompiler[globalI] = {unit: unitNumber[globalI], data: []};

      let iframeObj = document.createElement('iframe');
      iframeObj.id = `iframe_${globalI}`;
      iframeObj.hidden = false;
      iframeObj.src = url;
      iframeObj.onload = () => {
        if (loadFinished[unitNumber[globalI]] == false) {
            loadFinished[unitNumber[globalI]] = true;
            let setDate = "11/01/2019";
            iframeLoaded(globalI, unitNumber[globalI], setDate);
            console.log("iframeloaded called on " + globalI);
            setTimeout(() => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                    let dateCheckObject = {}, rowCount = checkRowCount(globalI), trackingArr = [];
                    if (rowCount == 0) {
                      globalCompiler[globalI].data.push(" ");
                    } else {
                      for (let inc = 1; inc <= rowCount; inc++) {
                        //let check = $('#iframe_'+globalI).contents().find(`.Row` + inc).html().includes("Pre Trip");
                        let check = document.querySelector(`#iframe_${globalI}`).contentWindow.document.querySelector(".Row"+inc).outerHTML
                        if (check.includes("Pre Trip")) {
                          dateCheckObject.pre = true;
                        } else {
                          dateCheckObject.post = true;
                        }
                      }
                      if(dateCheckObject.pre && dateCheckObject.post) {
                        console.log("X");
                        globalCompiler[globalI].data.push("X");
                        dateCheckObject = {};
                      } else if (dateCheckObject.pre == 'undefined') {
                        console.log("NO PRE");
                        globalCompiler[globalI].data.push("NO PRE TRIP");
                        dateCheckObject = {};
                      } else {
                        console.log("NO POST");
                        globalCompiler[globalI].data.push("NO POST TRIP");
                        dateCheckObject = {};
                      }
                }
              },500);
            }, 20000);
        }
    };
      document.body.appendChild(iframeObj);

      console.log("Global Loop called");
    }
    ```
````

Comment: How do you know there's no CORS issue?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! The iframes load urls from the same domain, i.e. no issues with XSS or CORS. :O

I'm not sure why, but it feels like there is a timing issue... Which is why I made the onload function wait 20 seconds before even starting the scripts. But that still gives the same error. It's almost like the function takes a snapshot of what is available at the time of setTimeout then runs the code..

Answer (score 0):

A for loop ran one count too far...

e.g.: `for (let inc = 1; inc <= rowCount; inc++)`
Should have been `for (let inc = 1; inc < rowCount; inc++)`